# angularjs select the first value in select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-options

I need to highlight the first value 'fullName' in select box using angularjs.
I am using angularstrap selectbox.

**controller,**

```
  $scope.accountInfo.owners = [  
   {  
      "accounts":null,
      "phoneumber":null,
      "email":null,
      "fullName":"MITA DASGUPTA",
      "mobilePhoneNumber":null,
      "noteFlag":false,
      "number":130000000484
   }
]
```

Template,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" placeholder="Pleasae select" 
  data-ng-model="owner.fullName" 
  data-html="1" 
  bs-options="owner as owner.fullName for owner in accountInfo.owners"  
  bs-select>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

I tried that way, but the value not selecting by default.

Comment: I stuck up in the middle, any body can help ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have some different ng-model name you already used `owner` in `ng-options` like `selectedOwner`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" placeholder="Pleasae select" 
  data-ng-model="selectedOwner" 
  data-html="1" 
  bs-options="owner as owner.fullName for owner in accountInfo.owners"  
  bs-select>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Then you need to set value of `ng-model` from controller.

```
$scope.selectedOwner = $scope.accountInfo.owners[0];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Its working fine. I struggled a lot since morning

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize the model which is capturing the selected values. You usually achieve this with an [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) but it is also possible to intialize your model in your controller with the first element of your array. (And the appropriate field).

Comment: i am using angular strap selectbox

Comment: I saw. In the documentation they initialize a begin value in the controller. I.e. $scope.selectedIcons = "["Globe","Heart"]";